# how to create dynamic nav items using next js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch-api

It seems nextjs getStaticProps is not working in components but working in pages. But I need to fetch api data to my components. Is there anyway to this?

I've tried this but I'm not happy with the process .

```
    const [data, setData]=useState();


useEffect(()=>{
    async function fetchData() {
      const res = await fetch(
        'https://domainname/api/vb1/category-tree'
      );
      const {data} = await res.json();
      setData(data)
    }
    fetchData()
  },[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to statically generate certain components using `getStaticProps`. In my opinion, the easiest way to do this would be to fetch the data you need in the page where your component is being used and pass the data as props to the component.

Comment: I want to fetch data to my navbar.. And its kinda nested. I have two navbar. Main navbar child is second navbar. In second navbar I want to fetch some data. Now my layout component looks like this : <Nav/>{children}<Footer/>

Comment: Where should I make request?

Comment: If you're using it in a layout component, then that rules out the possibility of generating it statically because then you would have to run `getStaticProps` on a per-page basis, which isn't optimal. Your current implementation using client-side rendering with `useEffect` is the way to in my opinion. In terms of where to make the request, make it in the component closest to where it is used, which in your case, I believe, is in the second navbar.

Comment: But how can I get details?  like if i used getStaticProps I could've use getStaticPath to fetch single item. Now how can do it? I am totally lost

Comment: By details, do you mean dynamic routing, in that you need to get some string from a path that you can then use to fetch data? In that case, you can statically generate those pages by fetching the slugs/paths in `getStaticPaths`, then fetching the data in `getStaticProps` and then passing the data from getStaticProps to the second navbar via props.